# Splunk SAML SSO from an IdP with Apache mod_mellon fails

Tags: single-sign-on, splunk, saml

I am trying to configure SSO from an IdP to Apache with mod_mellon and mod proxy to splunk.

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04; Apache 2.4.7; mod-auth-mellon 0.7.0.

Apache configured with the mellon-generated key / cert on default ssl site. mod proxy is being used to proxy to splunk locally on port 8000.

`auth_mellon.conf`:

```
MellonCacheSize 100
MellonLockFile "/var/lock/mod_auth_mellon.lock"
MellonPostDirectory "/var/cache/apache2/mod_auth_mellon/"

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /secret/ !
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
<Location />
        MellonEnable "info"
        Require valid-user
        AuthType "Mellon"
        MellonVariable "cookie"
        MellonSamlResponseDump On
        MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_splunk.key
        MellonSPCertFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_splunk.cert
        MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_splunk.xml
        MellonIdpMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/idp-meta.xml
        MellonEndpointPath /secret/endpoint
        MellonUser "NAME_ID"
        MellonDefaultLoginPath /en-US/
        RequestHeader set SplunkWebUser %{MELLON_NAME_ID}e
        MellonSamlResponseDump On

        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000/
        ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
</Location>
```

`idp-meta.xml` contains the metadata from the IDP (including the IDP x509 cert and HTTP Post / HTTP Redirect parameters). the `urn_service.*` files are generated from a `mellon_create_metadata.sh` script that creates an x509 cert and key on the SP and xml config file.

When I try access the splunk from the IdP, I see errors in the apache log file, and get a 500 / internal server error response:

```
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802): AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[core:error] AH00027: No authentication done but request not allowed without authentication for /secret/endpoint/login. Authentication not configured?
```

It seems like the SAML authentication is failing. I am following this guide: http://blogs.splunk.com/2013/10/09/splunk-sso-using-saml-through-okta/

Splunk is configured to authenticate with LDAP, and is authenticating correctly. Does apache also need to be configured with ldap authentication to identify valid-users too? (not sure about how users are authenticated in apache/mellon, assumed that's all handled by the payload from IdP and mellon just knows about the identity

Comment: Can you post (anonymized) the dump of the mellon saml response?

Comment: Not sure how to get the dump. I have `MellonPostDirectory "/var/cache/apache2/mod_auth_mellon/"` and both `MellonSamlResponseDump` and `MellonPostReplay` set to `On` but not finding anything in that directory.

Comment: "If MellonSessionDump is set, then the SAML session will be available in the MELLON_SESSION environment variable". So it looks you need to setup a service html page to dump data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a number of things were wrong. Firstly, I didn't realize that the metadata needed to be recopied from my IdP back to the apache configs when I modified the SAML settings that side. Anyway, after making sure the IdP and SP xml files were configured correctly in Apache, I was able to move on (I think I had changed the entity ID)

I was still getting an error around requiring a valid user in the error logs. It turns out that `MellonEnable "auth"` takes care of ensuring there's a valid user, while for some reason, `Require valid-user` and `AuthType "Mellon"` parameters were triggering errors and 500 server responses.

After removing these 2 directives, I was still getting errors, this time `Could not find metadata for the IdP "(null)"` - after a quick search, it turns out that latest version of `lasso` available on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (2.4.0) does not work with the SHA256 signatures that the IdP was defaulting to. Lasso 2.5 support SHA256. After updating the IdP config with a compatible algorithm, identification was taking place correctly.

However, I was then faced with redirect loops because of the context. I found another post that suggested moving the web root of splunk to a `/splunk` context instead of at root (`/`), and by updating this, I am now able to authenticate to Splunk via mellon from the IdP.  Here's the relevant working configs:

```
MellonLockFile "/var/lock/mod_auth_mellon.lock"
MellonPostDirectory "/var/cache/apache2/mod_auth_mellon/"

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
# Move the proxy directives out of <location> and specify the context / mapping
ProxyPass /splunk http://127.0.0.1:8000/splunk
ProxyPassReverse /splunk http://127.0.0.1:8000/splunk

<Location />
        MellonEnable "info"
        MellonVariable "cookie"
        MellonSamlResponseDump On
        MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_splunkweb.key
        MellonSPCertFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_splunkweb.cert
        MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_splunkweb.xml
        MellonIdpMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/idp-metadata.xml
        MellonEndpointPath /secret/endpoint
        MellonUser "NAME_ID"
        MellonDefaultLoginPath /splunk/en-US/
        RequestHeader set SplunkWebUser %{MELLON_NAME_ID}e
        ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
</Location>
<Location /splunk/>
        # Forces /splunk requests to be authenticated via the IdP.
        MellonEnable "auth"
</Location>
```

$SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/web.conf:

```
[settings]
trustedIP=127.0.0.1
remoteUser SplunkWebUser
SSOMode=permissive
root_endpoint = /splunk
```

And $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/server.conf

```
[general]
trustedIP=127.0.0.1
```

This is obviously for a setup where the apache/mellon server runs on the same host as splunk. `web.conf` (splunk) and `auth_mellon.conf` (apache) need to be updated with remote IPs if not. `web.conf` supports a comma-separated list of trusted hosts, while `server.conf` doesn't and should stay as localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Stage a debug web page with the following:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

foreach($_SERVER as $key=>$value) {
  if(substr($key, 0, 7) == 'MELLON_') {
    echo($key . '=' . $value . "\r\n");
  }
}
?>
```

Can you check whether the users'id is in the

```
  MellonUser "NAME_ID"
```

`NAME_ID` attribute? It looks suspicious to me. Usually it is `uid` or similar. In test phase you could change to any attribute you know IdP releases (mail, cn... whatever) just to avoid the 500 issue.

Comment: It looks like it's something to do with the setup of the location. If I set up the example from the mod mellon wiki, I am able to authenticate. I had a number of things wrong initially, specifically different namespaces in the IdP to mellon / sp setup (needed to re-download the metadata after making changes in the IdP). `MELLON_NAME_ID` is the correct field that I am looking for. Also not sure if there is an issue in the mod proxy / proxypass configuration, but now that I have the sample authenticating as expected I am going to work through the real service setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the debug page @473183469, helped figure out the issues and come to a working solution, posted below.

Comment: `NAME_ID` is correct, that is what the IdP passes back.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably IDP is not correctly configured with the LDAP & there is no extra configuration need for Mellon/Apache.

If you can post the dump of SAML response that will help to further drilldown the issue.

Please let me know if you want to discuss further.

Thanks,
Sandy
E- Sandy@mirketa.com

Comment: IdP was working correctly, was SP configuration in apache / mellon.